# CKEditor will append a root into my image link

Tags: php, jquery, ckeditor

When I post an image in my CKEditor, the link will add a server root address before the start of the actual URL. Why does it behave like that and how can I solve it?

Thank you.

Example error:

> http://www.myserver.hk/%22http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/sfs_icon_forward.png/%22

This is how it look like in the html format

```
<img id="\&quot;headerImage" campaign-icon\"="" mc:allowdesigner="\&quot;\&quot;" mc:allowtext="\&quot;\&quot;" mc:edit="\&quot;header_image\&quot;" mc:label="\&quot;header_image\&quot;" src="\&quot;http://gallery.mailchimp.com/653153ae841fd11de66ad181a/images/placeholder_600.gif\&quot;" style="\&quot;max-width:600px;\&quot;">
```

Comment: are you using the default image insert  (from url) or a plugin, could you provide the parameters you are starting the CKEditor with?

Comment: can you post ur ckeditor settings/plugins

Answer (score 1):

You should debug your image.js plugin on CKEditor.

Look for the "onOk" event on it and try to understand what's going on. The onOk event is fired when you click on the "Ok" button on the Image Modal that show up when you click on the image button on your toolbar.

Probably there you will find the answer for you problem.

That's my image.js: http://pastebin.com/ApQb4d5Z